# Deploy multiple ear on webshphe 8.5.5 using jython script

Tags: websphere, jython, ear

With below **jython** script I am able to deploy single ear in **8.5.5**

```
AdminApp.install('/tmp/ear/test.ear', '[ -nopreCompileJSPs -distributeApp -nouseMetaDataFromBinary -appname \"xyzApplication\" -createMBeansForResources -noreloadEnabled -nodeployws -validateinstall warn -noprocessEmbeddedConfig -filepermission .*\.dll=755#.*\.so=755#.*\.a=755#.*\.sl=755 -noallowDispatchRemoteInclude -noallowServiceRemoteInclude -asyncRequestDispatchType DISABLED -nouseAutoLink -MapModulesToServers [[ .* .*,WEB-INF/web.xml WebSphere:cell=xyzcell,cluster=xyzcluster ]] -MapRolesToUsers [[ ExcludeAuth AppDeploymentOption.Yes AppDeploymentOption.No \"\" \"\" AppDeploymentOption.No \"\" \"\" ][ \"All Role\" AppDeploymentOption.No AppDeploymentOption.No \"\" \"\" AppDeploymentOption.Yes \"\" \"\" ]] -MapWebModToVH [[ .* .*,WEB-INF/web.xml default_host ]]]' )
```

Now I have two ear file inside /tmp/ear/ directory and i want deploy both , So can I use regular expression in place of **test.ear**, like below ***.ear**

```
AdminApp.install('/tmp/ear/*.ear', '[ -nopreCompileJSPs -distributeApp -nouseMetaDataFromBinary -appname \"xyzApplication\" -createMBeansForResources -noreloadEnabled -nodeployws -validateinstall warn -noprocessEmbeddedConfig -filepermission .*\.dll=755#.*\.so=755#.*\.a=755#.*\.sl=755 -noallowDispatchRemoteInclude -noallowServiceRemoteInclude -asyncRequestDispatchType DISABLED -nouseAutoLink -MapModulesToServers [[ .* .*,WEB-INF/web.xml WebSphere:cell=xyzcell,cluster=xyzcluster ]] -MapRolesToUsers [[ ExcludeAuth AppDeploymentOption.Yes AppDeploymentOption.No \"\" \"\" AppDeploymentOption.No \"\" \"\" ][ \"All Role\" AppDeploymentOption.No AppDeploymentOption.No \"\" \"\" AppDeploymentOption.Yes \"\" \"\" ]] -MapWebModToVH [[ .* .*,WEB-INF/web.xml default_host ]]]' )
```

Can I deploy both the ear inside xyzApplication? or there should be two different application.